# Can hilt get a bean based on the fully qualified path of the class?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have a list queried from the database.

```kotlin
val works = workRepository.getAllWork()
```

Then call different methods according to different ids.

```kotlin
works.forEach { work ->
    when {
      work.id == 1 -> {
        // do some thing
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

But there is a problem here, as you can see, it is hardcoded here `work.id == 1`.

So I hope to get the fully qualified path name of the class that executes the method from the database, and then use hilt to get the Bean created by this class.

I checked hilt's documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a similar function mentioned, what should I do?